# Jaspersoft Server pro : How to create a report online from a domain without selecting an Ad Hoc View?

Tags: jasperserver

I'm downloading JasperReports Server pro 5, install it.
Everything's ok.

First, I create a datasource, the link is ok. Then I create a domain.
And finally I want to create a report from scratch but the only thing I can do is selecting an Ad Hoc.[image]

I want to create a report from scratch, not to select an Ad Hoc View.
Could you tell me how to do it or what I do wrong ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in iReport.

1) Create a Repository Connection  to the jasperserver where domain is hosted

2) Go to file menu , Click on New , Select Domain Report from left panel

3) Select the jasperserver connection which you created in step 1

4) Select the Domain which you want to use to create report  Click next

5) Go to Window menu on Top , select Domain window .Domain window will appear on lower left

corner . It will be having all the fields exposed by domain .

6)  Right click on  any Field and then select Add (to report) . It will be added in fields

section. Select all fields one by one.

7) Now you have all the fields @ your disposal . You can just drag drop couple of them in

detail band and click on preview.

8) You can publish this report by clicking publish button in Domain window. After you

publish , you can access this report in jasperserver UI.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the menu Create -> Ad Hoc View

That's the starting point to "create a report from scratch". It will let you select the data that you want. Sometimes this is the end (when all you wanted to do was to analyze the data). But in your case you will probably proceed to save a report after you've gotten the data you want. Then you'll have a traditional report that can schedule or use for whatever purposes you want.